# find all paths in graph without start or end node

Tags: python, graph

I'm playing a game in which to proceed to the next level, we must defeat each level before it. Each level corresponds to a certain letter.

I've represented this as a graph traversal problem, but I'm trying to find all paths in a graph without a start or end node.

My graph is represented as a dictionary, with the key being strings and the values being a list of strings.

```
{
'A2': ['A1', 'B'], 
'A1': [], 
'B': [], 
'C': ['A2'],
 }
```

To go to level A2, we must complete A1 and B.

For example, an example path would be A1, B, A2, C. 
Another path could be B, A1, A2, C.

Implementations of depth first search or breadth first search require a start node. I'm thinking a good start node would be any key whose values are empty: in this case, A1 and B, but I'm uncertain how to implement dfs or bfs with two start nodes.

I've been working with tweaking this implementation of finding paths, but this only works with a start level and an end level.

```
def find_path(graph, start, end, path=[]):
        path = path + [start]
        if start == end:
            return path
        if start not in graph:
            return None
        for node in graph[start]:
            if node not in path:
                newpath = find_path(graph, node, end, path)
                if newpath: return newpath
        return None

print(find_path(course_dict, 'A1', 'PC'))
```

but I'm getting None for my answer.

Comment: Is there a reason you're writing your own graph traversal algorithm as-opposed to using a graph library like [NetworkX](http://networkx.github.io/) or [igraph](http://igraph.org/)?

Comment: Just practicing with python.

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: `but I'm trying to find all paths in a graph without a start or end node`. Would not make more sense to look at all the paths that bring you to the final level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, two problems.
First you are trying to built a recursive algorithm but you still use a for loop. That is confusing, you can do this without the for loop. It is not wrong to use a loop in a recursive algorithm but if you change your data structure you do not need to.

Second thing is that your dictionary is wrong. I assume that every key of the dictionary is the staring node and every value is a possible end node. This is how your algorithm currently works. In that case the end node for your start `A1` is not given. Therefore you get the None output.

The biggest problem is that you use the wrong algorithm. This algorithm finds a way from your start to your end node. But you want to ensure that every node between your start and end node is at least once visited. So you can either change the algorithm (which would be easy) or the data structure (which will lead to a lot of variations).

Comment: I think my question is how do I modify the above algorithm such that the end node is not needed?

Comment: Basically you use the wrong algorithm. This algorithm  only makes sure that there is a way from start to end.